# JWT auth with [Authorize] attribute

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt

Could someone shed a light on how default Asp.Net core attribute [Authorize] (with using Asp.Net Identity) understands how it should decode JWT token and get necessary info for granted access?
While forming JWT token I put in token RoleClaims for the user, does [Authorize] base on claims to grant them access to specific actionMethod

Answer (score 0):

You can access your claims using the following code:

```
User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(el => el.Type == claim)?.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

More details please follow this link 
[Create JWT & Authorize](https://youtu.be/ZiCTLggq-aQ)

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post()
    {
        var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        IEnumerable<Claim> claim = identity.Claims;
        var UserName = claim.Where(c => c.Type == "UserName").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();

        return "Welcome to " + UserName + "!";
    }
```